# How to change confidence interval level of marginsplot in Stata

Tags: stata, margins, confidence-interval

Is it possible to change the confidence interval level (say from the default 95% to 90%) when using Stata's `marginsplot` command? It does not seem to accept the `level(90)` option or keep information from a preceding `margins, level(90)` command.

Comment: Please read the _Asking_ section in http://stackoverflow.com/help on how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 1):

Please post **exact code** along with your explanation of what went wrong. It's difficult to assess what the problem is if you don't do that. This works fine (from the help file):

```
clear
set more off

webuse nhanes2

regress bpsystol agegrp##sex
margins agegrp
marginsplot, level(80)
```

Comment: Dear Roberto, thank you for you prompt response. I am using STATA 12. My code is: `nbreg pprev i.major##c.efrac civilwar lpoplog lgdplog lpolity lpolitysq lpprev enr, vce (cluster ccode) level(90)`
`margins major, at(efrac==(0(.1)1)civilwar=0 lpprev=0) atmeans level(90)`
`marginsplot, recast(line) recastci(rarea) yline(0) level(90)` STATA returns: "option level() not allowed". I get the same msg when running the code you posted above. Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It seems to work if I `set level 90, permanently` before running the three commands without the `level()` option... Problem solved.